# bind event handlers to cloned element using jQuery .clone()

Tags: jquery

I am using `.clone(true, true)` to create a copy of a DOM element that has many event handlers bound to children elements. The handlers are bound using #id selectors. So, when I clone the element and then perform an action (say a click), the handler fires properly, but on the original element.

It's obvious why it does this, but my question is - is there a way to work around this? Any way to get the actions to fire either on both elements, or only on the cloned elements (without rewriting a bunch of code that relies on #id selectors)?